# Android Facebook SDK get friend list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get user's who is logged into my app friend list. So, I need to use this code to do that:

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me/friends",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

The problem is that I don't know what I need to write into onCompleted method to put friend list to array.

Answer (score 0):

after the data comes to onCompleted() you can do something like this to see the structure of the json response,

> Log.d("-@-", "graph response " + response.getJSONObject());

this gives the structure of the json object from there you can get the data.
Also i think your app needs to go through facebook submission as there is other permissions your app needs to get friends of a person